# Entering Debug Mode After Code Execution Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, pycharm

I ran a code with a *for* loop, which takes a pretty long time. At the very end of the execution, I get the error message, plus the following :

```
KeyError: 0
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now since my code is very long to run, is it possible to enter debug mode from there to directly navigate to the iteration which cause the error? I am working specifically on pycharm, but this is more of a general question.

If it is not possible through the debugger, is there any other way?
thanks for your help!

PS: I had ran this code already with a small number in the *for* loop, which worked fine, but with a great number of iterations I get this error at the very end.

Comment: You can wrap things into a try/except, and under except block drop to `breakpoint()` which will enter a debugger.

Comment: However, it appears you may have a call where a dictionary does not have a key `0`. Check you can handle such cases with `mydict.get(key)` rather than `mydict[key]`.

Comment: Hi @Sazzy, thanks for the answer, my question is can I do it without rerunning the entire code? And yes it is an issue with a dictionary :) I will check with mydict.get(key)

Comment: You said you ran a small sample of your code which worked fine. Put incorrect data into your sample, and debug that first before running on a large scale.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [PyCharm documentation on debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html). Effectively, you set a breakpoint and then use the "run debug" instead of the standard "run" button.